# Error when publishing page that has a custom user control on it

Tags: web-part, error, page-layout, user-controls

I have a custom user control which is a "subscribe form". The user enters name, email etc and selects values from dropdowns I data bind from lists. I can view the page no problem and use the form but if I try to edit a page with the user control and then publish it I get the "This page contains content that is not valid. You can find more information in the affected sections."

code:

```
   private void DataBindDropdowns()
    {
                string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;
                using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(siteUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        //Bind the Title (Mr/Mrs/..) dropdown
                        SPList titleList = oWebsite.Lists[Constants.ListNames.SubscribeFormTitles];
                        if (titleList != null)
                        {
                            List<ListItem> source = new List<ListItem>();
                            source.Add(new ListItem("Please select", "Please select"));
                            source.AddRange(titleList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
                                .Select(pa => new ListItem(pa.Title, pa.Title))
                                .OrderBy(pa => pa.Text));
                            ddlTitles.DataSource = source;
                            ddlTitles.DataBind();
                        }

                        SPList interestList = oWebsite.Lists[Constants.ListNames.SubscribeFormInterest];
                        if (interestList != null)
                        {
                            var collListItems = from i in interestList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
                                                where i[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] != null
                                                orderby i[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title]
                                                select i;
                            chkInterest.DataSource = collListItems;
                            chkInterest.DataBind();
                        }

                        SPList formTextList = oWebsite.Lists[Constants.ListNames.SubscribeFormText];
                        if (formTextList != null)
                        {
                            var collListItems = formTextList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>();
                            ltTop.Text = collListItems.First()[Constants.FieldNames.TopText].ToString();
                            ltBottom.Text = collListItems.First()[Constants.FieldNames.BottomText].ToString();
                            SubscribeFormTitle.InnerText = collListItems.First().Title.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

Is there anything obvious in the code that can cause this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be using validation controls for name, email etc .If so, Use Validation group so that validation happens only on the button click of user control.

Comment: I already figured out the problem and you're correct. I also don't need to display the user control in edit mode so I put it in an editmodepanel with attribute PageDisplayMode="Display"